# How to call a function in mfc...?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I am new to MFC PROGRAMMING. I use vs 2008, in a Dialog Based App. I want to call bellow function on a button click event...?
    When I call like SortList(listboxone); is giving an error that SortList not found...!
    Please help me..!!

```
void SortList(CListBox& templistbox)
{   
    DWORD_PTR abc;
    int a=templistbox.GetCurSel();// Select current  Item Index    
    if(a<templistbox.GetCount()-1)
    {
        abc = (DWORD_PTR )templistbox.GetItemData(a);
        a++;
        templistbox.SetItemData(a,(DWORD_PTR) templistbox.GetItemData(templistbox.GetCurSel()));
    }
}
```

Sorry now I changed the function to as above but still gives same error.

Comment: Where are you calling the function? Is the function in the same file?

Comment: Why in the world is this tagged C# and .NET?  Fixed.

Comment: yes The function is in the same file.

Comment: If you really are calling SortList(listboxone) then there is no such function. The source code above shows a function that requires two int's and a CListBox as arguments.

Comment: Show the calling code please.

Comment: Dear-@roger_rowland I have editted the code as above. Removed the function arguments but still the same error is prompted, I saved the project rebuilded but not succeeded.

Comment: It says that "error C3861:'SortList':identifier not found"

Answer (score 2):

You probably are calling the function **above** the function definition. In C/C++, you need to define the function (or it's *prototype* at least) **before** calling the function. Put this:

```
void SortList(CListBox& templistbox);
```

at the the top of the source file.

Comment: Well, not entirely true. You can declare *or* define the function, before using it. You can even do both, if you want, but you must do at least one of those two.